# Varying ImageView source according to value

Tags: android, imageview

I would like to show something similar to a progressbar by using different images, for example an empty lawn if **progress = 0** and a nearly complete house if **progress = 95.**

I have 30 files named image1.jpg .... image30.jpg

Would it be possible to set the Drawable of an ImageView by using a string for the file name? That way I could just get an int between 1 and 30 from the progress and add that to a string that I use to set the Drawable.

I have read this:
[Android: Imageview showing an image according to edittext option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223232/android-imageview-showing-an-image-according-to-edittext-option)
but I don't want to write code for every case as I would like to use this function at different places of a project.

I would be very grateful for any help, either on how I can use strings and filenames for the Drawable or if there is another way of solving this.

Best regards,
Emil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setImageSrc(int i){
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naviView);
    iv.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("image"+i, "drawable", "com.example"));
}
```

You can retrieve the id if you know the name of the resources and then set the image via the id you determined earlier